# Install pip3 latest version for python3.6

Tags: 14.04, python, pip

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 and i recently installed python 3.6 since the default python version is 2.7 i used an alias to python 3.6 (`alias python=python3`) in `~/.barchrc`.

Now when I type python in terminal the python 3.5 terminal opens. But when I type pip-V it shows the path of an older version which is python 3.4.

```
tromesh@TR:/usr/local/bin$ pip3 -V
pip 9.0.1 from /usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages (python 3.4)
```

How can I install pip3 for python 3.6? or how can I make python 3.6 as my default?

Answer (score 2):

I guess this may be because you installed Python 3.6 package does not contain pip,
e.g. the PPA maintainer does not package python3.6-pip.

You can download the tarball at python.org
and compile Python 3.6 yourself
(do not forget to install dependencies like `libssl-dev` first),
which has pip built-in.

```
sudo apt-get install libssl-dev
# download tarball from python.org
tar xf python-3.*.tar.xz
cd Python-3.6.*/
configure
make
sudo make install
```